# using grep and find commands - basic questions to help me sort it out in my simple mind

Tags: command-line, command

I am back with a second no-brainer question, but I would like to get this straight in my head.

I have an assignment in which I am charged with providing a command to find a file named test in my home directory (one command using find, and one using grep).  I understand that using find is just 'find ~/test', but using grep, wouldn't I have to search out a pattern within the file 'test'?  Or is there a way to search for the file (using grep), even if the file is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls ~ | grep test`

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that using find is just 'find ~/test'

No. `find ~/test` will also have a match for every file or directory under the directory `$HOME/test/`. Rather use `find ~ -type f -name test`.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment sounds unclear.  But yes, if you give any filenames to `grep`, it will look at the contents of the files and ignore the names of the files.  Perhaps you can grep the output of another command?  Maybe `ls` as @Reese suggested, or maybe a different `find` command.

Comment: Okay, appreciate that.  I understand now that it just has to be piped.  Makes sense, should have figured that on my own.  Sorry to bother, appreciate the help.  However, still a bit unclear on why find ~/test won't work?  Won't that just show all files under my home directory named test?

Comment: See @Benoit's answer.  The first argument to `find` should usually be a directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -R ~ | grep test
```

Explanation: `ls -R ~` will recursively list all files and directories in your home folder. `grep test` will narrow down that list to files (and directories) that have "test" in their name.